# ASPNET cause of CS0246:The type or namespace name 'UserRemoteSessionsDAO' could not be found error?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Everytime I run my project, this error keeps popping up:
[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpKFP.png)

The UserRemoteSessionsDAO.cs is a class file and it has already been created right over here and the project file presents no issues until runtime. I have been searching for a solution for an entire day and there have been no solutions so far.
[UserRemoteSessionsDAO.cs created directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iajtg.png)

```
    using Project.Data_Access_Layer;

    protected async void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tbUser.Text == "admin" || tbPass.Text == "admin")
        {
            Response.Redirect("LoginManager.aspx");
        }

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStr"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkUser = "select count(*) from Login where username = '" + tbUser.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        UserRemoteSessionsDAO ursDAO = new UserRemoteSessionsDAO();

        conn.Close();

        if (temp == 1)
        {
```

Code above shows that there is no issues when I called the UserRemoteSessionsDAO class. Namespace has also been declared as well. Am I missing anything?

Comment: If the code compiles, it could be that on the deployed folder the DLL wasn't updated

Comment: Is it alright if you can show me the file path to the deployed folder? This project has not been deployed yet.